# Page crashes when running draw function. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create an array of vectors, but I would like to draw lines to visualize them. When I run the code with the `drawGrid()` function included, the page crashes with no explanation. Here is the whole of my code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

class Vector {
    constructor(x, y, magnitude, angle) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.mag = magnitude
        this.ang = angle
        this.tx = magnitude * Math.cos(angle) + x
        this.ty = magnitude * Math.sin(angle) + y
    }

    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.moveTo(this.x, this.y)
        c.lineTo(this.tx, this.ty)
        c.stroke()
        
    }
}

const resolution = 20;

let grid = []

function init() {

    //creates grid of arrays
    for(let i = 0; i < canvas.height; i += resolution) {
        grid.push(new Array())
        for(let j = 0; j < canvas.width; j += resolution) {
            grid[i / resolution].push(new Vector(i, j, 7, Math.PI))
        }
    }

    drawGrid()
}

function drawGrid() {

    let vector
    for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        grid.push(new Array())
        for(let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            vector = grid[i][j]
            vector.draw()
            console.log(vector)
        }
    }

}

//run program
init()
```

When I remove the call to the `drawGrid` function, the page loads normally and, through adding `console.log(grid)`, I can see all the vectors generated as expected. It is only when it attempts to draw lines that the page crashes.

Comment: `grid.push(new Array())` is making the array grow to infinity as you iterate it.  Maybe you forgot to remove it when copying the init func.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. I'm using that to create a two-dimensional array, and I know the for loop terminates, as when adding `console.log(grid)` after the loop, I can see the result.

Comment: it really is the case!  I’m not telling you to remove the array push from init, but from draw.

Comment: Oh wow! I missed that. Thanks so much, that works!